# Do I need to check variable correlation before applying, NN or random forest?

Tags: random-forest, feature-selection

I'm applying RF, ANN & RNN to my time series data (I originally had 10 variables (date,price...etc) but I only picked date and price and transform it into time series. But then I remembered I skipped feature selection,  Do I need to do that ?

Comment: How exactly would you like to use the correlations?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It looks like you selected the date and price features, so how do you figure you skipped feature selection? // How is date a time series? Do you mean that you have something like a stock price as it changes on different dates?

Comment: @Dave After implementing RF and reviewing some basic data preprocessing I saw a step that mentioned variables selection & multivariate time series. And I thought maybe these other variables can make a difference in my prediction result but I don't know how important they are ? Or if they can affect stock price